rate limiter with PI controller

I need to implement a rate limiter to ensure that the output does not change at a rate higher than the specified limit. This rate limiter is placed before the PI controller in my simulation model. However, I am encountering issues while tuning the controller:

The system works for a specific rate limiter value if the PI controller is delicately tuned to accommodate that rate. Otherwise, if the rate limiter is set too low (or too slow), it leads to oscillations.
When using only proportional (P) control (by setting the integral (I) action to zero), there is a steady-state error, but the rate limiting seems to function correctly.

Is it correct to implement the rate limiter before the PI controller? I’ve noticed that in many references, the rate limiter is applied at the input side (immediately after ()).
If the placement of the rate limiter is correct, could the oscillations simply be a controller tuning issue?
edit

I want to limit how fast system output y(t) changes.
controller process (G(s)) is an electrical generator that delivers the power as set by controller reference r(t)
The controller is required to make sure that demanded r(t), changing every hour, is correctly reached at plant output y(t). However, with a certain ramp while input being a step change.


Hi, 1) I want to limit how fast system output y(t) changes. 2) controller process (G(s)) is an electrical generator that delivers the power as set by controller reference r(t) 3) disturbance is a step change in r(t). The controller is required to make sure that demanded r(t), changing every hour, is correctly reached at plant output y(t). However, with a certain ramp while input being a step change. Hope this clarifies.

"Disturbance is a step change in r(t)? Isn't r(t) directly set by the user? Why not then just put a rate limiter directly on r(t)? Why is it called a disturbance if it is directly set by the user?

Add clarifying information directly in the question using the [edit] link below the question. comments may not be seen by all users and may get deleted at a later time.

My bad.. r(t) is not a disturbance but an input set by the user. Putting rate limiter on r(t) is an option, but I am wondering why my controller doesn't work as if the rate limiter is placed before the PI?


The controller is required to make sure that demanded r(t), changing every hour, is correctly reached at plant output y(t). However, with a certain ramp while input being a step change.

Concept is called input shaping. Put the rate limiter directly on the signal r(t); i.e. to the left of the summing junction in the diagram.

Rate limiter cascaded with the controller is a non-linear insert, but intuitively it adds something which increases phase lag. I skip rigorous non-linear math analysis (=too complex). The total loop phase lag grows and reduces the stability phase margin. This can be compensated to some degree by tuning the controller. Inserting the limiter to r(t) doesn't affect the loop at all.
